# Can their be actioncontroller and no view for button in yii

Tags: button, yii, yii-extensions

I have a the register button which I have created in cgridview I need to know whether can we have action in controller buuton and no view for that particular action for that button in yii

view user

```
 <?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
  <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
  <?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
  'model'=>$model,
    )); ?>
  </div><!-- search-form -->

  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'product-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->countregister($_GET['id']),
  'enablePagination' => true,
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(

 'name',
 'email',

  array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{Register}{update}{view}',

    'buttons'=>array(
           'Register'=>array(
           'label'=>'Register',
           .'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create',array( 'email'=>$data->email) )
          )
           ),

 ),

 ),
 )); ?>
```

controller user

```
public function actionCreate($email)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($email);
    if($_SESSION['userid'])
    { 

        $this->redirect('product/create',array(       //line 1
        'model'=>$model,'id'=>$model->productid,
    ));
    }
    //$this->redirect(array('display','id'=>$model->productid));
    $this->redirect(array('user/login'));
}
```

i don get error  but then the below line not the url iam looking
    /localhost/test/index.php/register/create/product/create

it should be 
 /localhost/test/index.php/product/create/id/1

i think there's something wrong  in line 1

Please let me know how do i resolve this

Comment: can you explain what you are asking as it is not clear?

Comment: so you just want that if you click on that register button then that controller action should execute but no view is rendered. If this is what you are asking then yes, it is possible

Comment: yes :) that is wt i need

Comment: updated this is what have done but its nt working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44401/discussion-between-let-me-see-and-tisha)

Comment: i have update my question plz luk over

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$this->redirect('product/create',array(       //line 1
        'model'=>$model,'id'=>$model->productid,
```

to

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('product/create',array(       //line 1
       'id'=>$model->productid))
```

Comment: the abve code gives /localhost/test/index.php/product/create/             but then i need  ......  /localhost/test/index.php/product/create/id/1

Comment: id and its value is not been passed as querstring in the url

Comment: Dear you are trying to send $model which is an object in the url. you need to remove that

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrise your individual CButtonColumn instances:

```
array(
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{Register}{view}{update}',

    'buttons' => array(
        'Register' => array(
                'label' => 'Register',
           'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('register/create', array('email' => $data->email)),
            'visible'=>'$data->entries == 0',
          ),
        'view' => array(
            'visible'=>'$data->entries > 0',
        )
    )
),
```

But to answer you question after you updated your response (I was already typing it out)

You can use the raw type:

```
'type'=>'raw',
```

and the url becomes something like :

```
'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("register/create",array( "email"=>$data->email) )'
```

thx to @let-me-see

source: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/#hh2

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
$this->redirect(array('product/create','id'=>$model->productid));
```

Comment: obviously the problem was that you were trying to send the object as a parameter in the url

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Nicktar ya you are true this does not provide an answer to the question. it was for redirect ...... but the actioncreate does not have view .... the thing was a i was coming up with issues i was editing the  question ... i ensure you this wont happen in future